# PDO with self signed certificates

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

I'm still tryin to connect with PDO to a remote MySQL database. Customer provide self signed certificates, `client-key.pem` and `client-cert.pem`. Certificates are good, I can connect to remote db using mysql client.
This is where I instantiate a PDO object to connect to db.

```
pdoDb = new PDO(
  'mysql:host=customer_host_name;dbname=customer_db_name', 
  'my_username', 
  'my_password', 
  array(
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY=>'C:/Apache24/htdocs/CLIENT/lib/client-key.pem',
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'C:/Apache24/htdocs/CLIENT/lib/client-cert.pem'
  ));
```

I'm getting this error when I instantiate PDO object:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\Apache24\htdocs\CUSTOMER\lib\database.php on line 17
```

I think code was correct but I'm newbie to PHP.

***Update***
Pardon me. I forgot to mention that I didn't specify a value for  `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` because customer doesn't give me one. Sorry. Is `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` mandatory to `PDO` (or `mysqli`)?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Internet for the error message? There wre quite a few descriptions regarding this. Which have you tried so far and what was the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When generating your certificates you have to use the right "Common Name" for each one:

```
CA: hostname 
Server: FQDN, e.g. hostname.example.com 
Client: somename
```

The important part is the server certificate where the Common Name has to be the same as the host you are connecting to, e.g. hostname.example.com.

```
$pdoDb = new PDO(
  'mysql:host=customer_host_name;dbname=customer_db_name', 
  'my_username', 
  'my_password', 
  array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/CLIENT/lib/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/CLIENT/lib/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/CLIENT/lib/ca-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CIPHER => 'CAMELLIA128-SHA'
  )
);
```

Comment: Hello, I see you specify a `ca-cert.pem`. Customer doesn't provide me one but `client-key` and `client-cert` only, they're enought to connect to remote server. Is `ca-cert.pem` mandatory to PDO?

Comment: Franz, I don't think you really understand certificates if you're asking that question. The CA cert is just used for trusting purposes and is helpful with mutliple certificates.

Comment: Do you have openssl php extension and is it enabled?

Comment: Yes, I uncommented the `extension=php_openssl.dll` line.

Comment: As Charles has hinted at, the CA certificate which signed the SERVER certificate is not installed on the CLIENT

Comment: @symcbean yes and the very bad is that I didn't mention it in my question. That's why I was asking if `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` is mandatory to `PDO` (or `mysqli`). Better I update my question.